# Wordpress plugin template without using header and footer?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating plugin that uses single-{post-type}.php. My questions is, how can I create this file and not use:

```
get_header();
```

&

```
get_footer();
```

or is it not possible? My thought is that I just want it in the content area so this can be included in any theme and not break.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more? What is it that you want in the content area? Why is your plugin using a template that differs by theme? Why can't you use header and footer?

Comment: It's a location plugin, so I created a custom post type 'location', then I created a shortcode to display all locations. The shortcode can be placed anywhere so it can be put in any theme. Now when they click on one of those locations it takes them to the single page. I was hoping I could create that dynamically without using header and footer. I am afraid that if I use header and footer I might break it on some other theme, or is this normal practice?

Comment: Using get_header and get_footer shouldn't break your plugin. Unless your plugin conflicts with some enqueued scripts through a theme, but that's on them, not you. Without knowing too much about how your code is structured, I feel like you should be fine using the header and footer. In fact, I can't really think of a reason not to...

Comment: Ok, thanks so much!